showing number with decimal part as tooltip/hint for one column in power bi matrix
I wanted to show a number as percent  without decimal number with matrix in power bi
at the same time needs to show real number with exact decimal number when user pointing out to it /right click /tool tip ...
I've just want to do it for one column
any idea?
